# Push Notification Service - multiple developers

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, csr, code-signing-certificate

I am not sure how to handle situation where there are 2 or more developers which are cooperating by git and each is working on his own machine. How to create certificates for PNS correct? There should be multiple developers in Certificates right? But which one should create APNS development and distribution certificates (with own Certificate Signing Request, csr)? There shouldn't be more then 2 APNS certificates right? One for developing and one for distribution.

**So how can I make build for my device and get notifications and same for co-workers?**

Comment: push notification certificate does nothing about the development, it is used in your server to send notification payloads to APNS.

Comment: yes but they are created with csr (Certificate Signing Request) or it doesn't matter which person created it?

Comment: Doesn't matter. You download the cert and just use it anywhere